# I am trying to code a discord bot with JavaScript in Visual Studio Code, but I keep getting an error that Command name must be lowercase

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, discord

I am trying to code a discord bot with JavaScript in Visual Studio Code, but I keep getting an error that Command name must be lowercase.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\tjcol\Documents\bot_v1> node .
C:\Users\tjcol\Documents\bot_v1\node_modules\discord.js-commando\src\commands\base.js:52
                if(info.name !== info.name.toLowerCase()) throw new Error('Command name must be lowercase.');
                                                          ^

Error: Command name must be lowercase.
    at new Command (C:\Users\tjcol\Documents\bot_v1\node_modules\discord.js-commando\src\commands\base.js:52:51)
    at new TotalQCommand (C:\Users\tjcol\Documents\bot_v1\commands\random\totalQ.js:5:9)
    at CommandRegistry.registerCommands (C:\Users\tjcol\Documents\bot_v1\node_modules\discord.js-commando\src\registry.js:114:48)
    at CommandRegistry.registerCommandsIn (C:\Users\tjcol\Documents\bot_v1\node_modules\discord.js-commando\src\registry.js:166:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tjcol\Documents\bot_v1\index.js:6:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

Comment: probable because the value of `info.name` is not lower case - debugging 101 tip: console.log(info.name) prior to that line of code to see what it is

Comment: what looks odd is the combination of `Windows PowerShell` and `node`

Comment: @JaromandaX that's possibly the debug output when running it.

Comment: Provide your code so we can actually do something about your issue

Comment: Are you using discord.js?

Comment: It looks like OP is using `discord.js-commando`

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs for [`discord.js-commando`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/general/welcome), your command name must be lowercase.

See the [`Command`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/class/Command) -> [`CommandInfo`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/typedef/CommandInfo) docs:

```
PARAMETER   TYPE    OPTIONAL    DEFAULT DESCRIPTION
name        string              The name of the command (must be lowercase)
...
```

You can see the code line that throws the error and is referenced in your console output - `if(info.name !== info.name.toLowerCase()) throw new Error('Command name must be lowercase.');` - in the [Commando Github repo](https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/blob/master/src/commands/base.js#L419).